# five fold Cross-validation for different value of k(knn) in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, precision, cross-validation, knn

I have data set (https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/glass/glass.data).
I need to perform 5 fold cross validation and plot PR curves for three different values of k (knn) and random prediction. I have to Use as confidence threshold the proportion of neighbours agreeing in the predicted class.
I know that I need to use Euclidean distance function, split the data in 5 parts and make train and test set. but i dont know how i can implement in R without using package and i have to provide pseudo code for knn implementation. Please help. If anything is not clear Ill try to explain again.

Comment: This sounds like a homework/assignment question. You'd be better off searching Google. I'm sure there are enough resources on the web to help you.

Comment: @TejaK I got the articles about KCV and knn separately. here i am confused about how i do KCV and knn?